# NN Model accuracy and loss is not changing with the epochs!

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, prediction

I am building a tensorflow model for Heart Disease Prediction data-set. It has a binary outcome (0, 1).
Though I am struck with such a low accuracy which is not changing with epochs.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(13,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_data, train_label, epochs=100)
```

The accuracy and the Loss is not changing with the Epochs

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'NoneType'>
Train on 227 samples
Epoch 1/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 312us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 2/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 68us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 3/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 4/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 74us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 5/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 6/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 7/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 82us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 8/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 9/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 10/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 11/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 12/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 13/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 14/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 80us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 15/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 65us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 16/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 65us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 17/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 18/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 19/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 70us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 20/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 21/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 22/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 23/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 77us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 24/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 74us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 25/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 62us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 26/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 62us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 27/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 28/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 29/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 67us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 30/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 67us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 31/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 63us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 32/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 62us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 33/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 34/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 82us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 35/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 36/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 37/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 38/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 39/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 40/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 64us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 41/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 82us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 42/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 43/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 80us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 44/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 68us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 45/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 46/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 47/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 67us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 48/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 67us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 49/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 50/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 51/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 52/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 53/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 70us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 54/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 55/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 56/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 57/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 63us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 58/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 74us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 59/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 75us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 60/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 61/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 62/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 63/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 64/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 65/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 66/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 67/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 70us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 68/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 69/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 68us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 70/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 65us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 71/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 68us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 72/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 73/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 74/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 80us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 75/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 76/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 77/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 75us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 78/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 79/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 80/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 77us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 81/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 82/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 83/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 84/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 85/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 86/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 75us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 87/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 74us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 88/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 71us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 89/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 73us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 90/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 102us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 91/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 74us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 92/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 73us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 93/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 66us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 94/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 95/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 65us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 96/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 67us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 97/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 72us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 98/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 99/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 69us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
Epoch 100/100
227/227 [==============================] - 0s 64us/sample - loss: 7.0925 - accuracy: 0.5374
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f374e3101d0>
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for low accuracy :

- Your data is not balanced
- Your data is not related to your output
- Your model is very complex
- Wrong selection of hyperparameters

Ideally you should do a feature correlation check in beginning. Instead, To rule out first 2 doubts, you can train a decision tree/Random forest. If you get decent accuracy then jump to neural networks.
Also check if your data is balanced and stratified across both classes.